# Formal way to describe sexual acts

Tags: word-usage, formality

I'm writing a statement of events that happened between me and my ex. It needs to be written formally but I don't how to write the following words in that way: "blowjob" and "eating her out." Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Can someone explain the downvotes? This seems [on topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), to me.

Comment: This should be closed as a general reference question.

Comment: The downvotes may reflect a disapproval of the tone of your request.  You do not just ask for alternative terms for slang, but purportedly refer to your ex's private activities. Not needed for the question, and bordering on offensive (not for the terms, but for the context).

Answer (score 17):

It sounds as if the words you need are *fellatio* and *cunnilingus*.

Comment: I think *oral sex* is also a good umbrella term for this type of sex act, although that answer was deleted.

Answer (score 2):

*Performed oral sex on each other* covers it as well. Although, as Barrie points out, *fellatio* (blow job) and *cunnilingus* (eating her out) are the technical terms for the exact acts, I would tend towards 'oral sex' as it is more generally understood and, well, sounds a bit more pleasant.